# How to put psql on the path when using Postgres.app on OS X?

Tags: macos, postgresql, psql

I've installed Postgres93 on my Mac. I can open the application, and "Open psql" through the app which opens up a command line interface with psql.

However, when I type `$ which psql` nothing is returned. The installation path is `/Applications/Postgres93.app`. How do I make `$ which psql` show the correct result?

Mac OS X - Mavericks

PostgreSQL package, I'm not as sure about. I went here and downloaded it - http://postgresapp.com/

Comment: Please always specify (a) your Mac OS X version, since Apple love changing stuff in random and exciting ways, and (b) What PostgreSQL packaging you are using - homebrew, heroku postgres.app, enterprisedb one-click, macports, etc. Easy to guess in this case, but only because you specified the path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that you installed Heroku's `Postgres.app`, which is a tool intended for throw-away testing and development. Add the contents of the bundle to your `PATH` by [following the instructions in the Postgres.app documentation](http://postgresapp.com/documentation) - see "command line tools".

Comment: 2020 update: The relevant section in the Postgres.app documentation is now written as "CLI Tools" instead of "command line tools".  On the "CLI Tools" page, see "Configure Your $PATH".

Answer (score 55):

I just had **postgres** installed and was not able to run the *psql* command until I ran the following command in my terminal:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin:$PATH"
```

Now the terminal knows where to find postgres when I use the *psql* command.

Remember to replace the version number '9.5' with your current version.

Comment: It's recommended to change that 9.5 to `latest`. There's a nice symlink in the Versions folder.

Comment: Thanks! I was not using the "App", but a regular PostreSQL installation, so my directory (and version) was different, but the principle is the same: `export PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/14/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem with nothing showing for the  **which psql** command till I run the command below to resolve it. The command provided below is just a little tweak of what has already been provided by others here. The only difference is, instead of providing a specific postgres version number in the command, you can simply tell postgres to use the latest postgres version by simply running the following command:

> export
>   PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"

And now my terminal was able to find the path to postgres when I run **which psql.**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

On macOS Mojave these instructions work well:

1. **If** your Postgres **has not been installed yet**, I suggest you use the great **"brew"** package manager from here https://brew.sh/ :

   `$ brew cask install postgres`
   or you can install it usual way from the website
2. Put this to the bottom of your **~/.bash_profile** file:

   `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:${PATH}"`
3. **Restart your terminal** or **restart your ~/.bash_profile** directly with the command:

   `$ . ~/.bash_profile`
4. Verify your installation:

   `$ psql --version`

Answer (score 12):

** Edited: to include a permanent fix, not just during your current session. **

I had this same problem, and also found a clear answer lacking in the docs.

To fix:

1. Download the new app, and follow the instructions to move it to the Applications folder
2. [Add the new bundle to your path](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/) by typing the following in your Terminal (version number specific - mine is 9.4):
   `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH"`
3. To fix the issue on a permanent basis, run the same line but with export in front:
   `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Does this change `$PATH` permanently? For me it only lasted until I closed the Terminal window. Editing the ~/.bash_profile file was the permanent solution in my case.

Answer (score 6):

On macos mojave i've added the following line on my **~/.profile** :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin
```

the psql command line client lies into this folder. i've used the [enterprisedb installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads).

Comment: This worked great for me. "10" referring to the installed PostgreSQL version, which today, if you've installed the latest version, would be "11". Above line would in that case be `export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/11/bin`.

Answer (score 5):

I just [experienced the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932347/postgres-app-setup-getting-which-psql-to-return-desired-path/29933012#29933012), and solved it by adding `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin` to .bash_profile.  Note that this line is version-specific, so be sure to check this line against your current version of Postgres.app.

Answer (score 2):

Using Mac OS Monterey, the latest `Homebrew (3.4.0)` and `postgres@13`.

I was able to add `psql` to the path by using -

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@13/13.6/bin:$PATH"
```

Replace `@13` and `13.6` with your version.

The latest homebrew install location seems to be `/opt/homebrew/*`

Answer (score 1):

### I'm using catalina 10.15.3 and I had the same issue after installing psql using homebrew. Then I noticed, homebrew mentioned

==> libpq
libpq is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because conflicts with postgres formula.

If you need to have libpq first in your PATH run:

### echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

So, I ran 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile and psql was added to my path

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, there is a SQL Shell application already under /Applications/PostgresSQL
try that

Also, you can run /Library/PostgreSQL/11/scripts/runpsql.sh

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed Postgres12 and had the same issue. I had to look out for the location of my bin folder. It happened to be in `/Applications/2ndQuadrant/PostgreSQL/12/bin`. So I had to run `export PATH="/Applications/2ndQuadrant/PostgreSQL/12/bin:$PATH"` in my terminal and restart the terminal. That solved it.