# Postgres.app setup: getting `which psql` to return desired path

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, terminal, bash

I just installed Postgres.app, and now **`which psql` returns nothing**.  I followed the [instructions listed on the Postgres site](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html); here's what I did:

1) Dragged my old version of Postgres to the trash.  Emptied trash.

2) Downloaded the current version of Postgres.app.  Dragged it to Applications folder.

3) Restarted Terminal.

**The output I'm looking for from `which psql` is something like:** `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/psql`

When I run `brew install postgresql` followed by `which psql`, I get `/usr/local/bin/psql`.  Which is at least something, but it's not what I want.

In case it's useful, here's my .bashrc:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    source ~/.bash_profile
fi

PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

And my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH

# Python
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
if [[ -r /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh ]]; then
    source /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh
else
    echo "WARNING: Can't find virtualenvwrapper.sh"
fi

export PS1="\h:\w \u\$ "

# for git
LESS="-qrX -P %lt"
export LESS

# colorize shell output
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=Hxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad

#========== ALIASES ===========

alias u="cd .."
alias uu="cd ../.."
alias uuu="cd ../../.."
alias cd..="cd .."
alias rm="rm -i"
alias ll="ls -laFGh"
alias ls="ls -FGh"
alias new="ls -lat | head -15"

# node needs to not have DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set
alias node="DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=''; node"

# postgres stuff
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution!  For posterity, here's what worked for me:

1) add the line `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin` to .bash_profile.  For further reading, I found this solution on the [Postgres.app Command Line Tools page](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html).

2) run `brew uninstall postgresql`.  This seems suboptimal, as I'll almost certainly want it later, but before uninstalling, the path to the brew-installed postgresql is all I got when I ran `which psql`.